# Configure Exim to relay emails using Office 365

Tags: exim, microsoft-office-365

I have configured exim using this article:
[EXIM: Relay to Office 365](https://serverfault.com/questions/727289/exim-relay-to-office-365)

I'm getting this error:

> Received TLS cert status response, itself unverifiable fixed_login
>   authenticator failed H=outlook-emeaeast2.office365.com
>   [132.245.61.226] 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

How can I resolve this?

Comment: the fail is not related to your router, will be better if you copy see all your exim.conf for other routers/authenticators/transports involved