# Configuring Exim to relay messages to an Office 365 server in Debian

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365, exim, debian-wheezy

Our company recently migrated from an on-site exchange server to Office 365. As a result of this, I need to update our proxy server to relay emails generated by our applications to Office 365. We are currently running exim4 on a Debian server. I can't seem to find any documentation for exim that explains what I need to update. The closest I have found is this: [EXIM: Relay to Office 365](https://serverfault.com/questions/727289/exim-relay-to-office-365) answer, but it seems to be for CentOS rather than Debian.

Can anyone provide me some help with this? What configuration settings do I need to change? How do I determine what the new values should be?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to track down the answer here: https://www.phpdeveloper.org.uk/using-office-365-as-a-mail-relay-with-exim-on-debian/

Running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` launched a wizard for inputting my configuration changes (the new hostname in my case) and then restarted exim.